# Software to estimate radiation dose for an orbit

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, radiation, simulation, reference-request

I am searching for a software/method, possibly open-source or free, to estimate the radiation dose for an orbit around earth.

Comment: [SPENVIS (Space Environment Information System)](https://www.spenvis.oma.be/) is free to use.

Comment: @Xukrao if that satisfies the OP"s description then I think you can post it as an answer if you like. Just add a sentence or two describing it, which can be simply copy/pasted and quoted from the site's description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SPENVIS](https://www.spenvis.oma.be) is free to use. It is described on its website as:

> SPENVIS is ESA's SPace ENVironment Information System, a WWW interface to models of the space environment and its effects; including cosmic rays, natural radiation belts, solar energetic particles, plasmas, gases, and "micro-particles".

> With SPENVIS, one can generate a spacecraft trajectory or a coordinate grid and then calculate:
>
> - geomagnetic coordinates
> - trapped proton and electron fluxes and solar proton fluences
> - **radiation doses (ionising and non-ionising) for simple geometries**
> - **a sectoring analysis for dose calculations in more complex geometries**
> - damage equivalent fluences for Si, GaAs and multi-junction solar cells
> - Geant4 Monte Carlo analysis for doses and pulse height rates in planar and spherical shields
> - ion LET and flux spectra and single event upset rates
> - trapped proton flux anisotropy
> - atmospheric and ionospheric densities and temperatures
> - atomic oxygen erosion depths

Comment: SPENVIS has been used on at least two NASA funded missions.